# MediaPlayer .setDataSource() causing exception in android

Tags: android, list, load, mp3, playback

I am making an android application that loads files from a directory on the sdcard into a list. Once an item is tapped, it resolves its path, and puts it into a string. I am trying to load the string into a mediaplayer with the .SetDataSource() method, but it force closes and causes an exception. How can i fix this? Please help me and thanks! Code is below:

```
package com.mysoftwaremobileapps.Cross;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MusicActivity extends ListActivity {
//Called when the activity is first created
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
EditText AddItemToListViewEditText;
  static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
      "Movies"
      };
  MediaPlayer mp1;
  String musicUri;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.musicscreen);

    //Setup ListView
    setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));
    setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, myList));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    File mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/");
    myList.addAll(Arrays.asList(mFile.list()));
    setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, myList));


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        //When an item is clicked, play it on a MediaPlayer
          try {
              musicUri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/" + myList.get(position);
            mp1.setDataSource(musicUri);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
    });
}
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
    07-03 21:25:42.031: D/ViewConsistency(5165): AbsListView android.widget.ListView@40588c48 enabled= true
07-03 21:25:42.051: D/ViewConsistency(5165): AbsListView android.widget.ListView@40588c48 enabled= true
07-03 21:25:43.691: D/AndroidRuntime(5165): Shutting down VM
07-03 21:25:43.691: W/dalvikvm(5165): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at com.mysoftwaremobileapps.Cross.MusicActivity$1.onItemClick(MusicActivity.java:52)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1877)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
07-03 21:25:43.721: E/AndroidRuntime(5165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 21:25:45.171: I/Process(5165): Sending signal. PID: 5165 SIG: 9
```

Comment: edit post with full log-cat stack trace when app is crashing

Comment: put `musicUri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/" + myList.get(position);System.out.println("Music Path Uri +++++++++++++ "+ musicUri);//mp1.setDataSource(musicUri);` instead of `musicUri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/" + myList.get(position); mp1.setDataSource(musicUri);` and check in log what music path you are receiving in musicUri

Comment: I have tested that musicUri brings up the correct data, it says the correct path. But when i am adding it, it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never instantiated the MediaPlayer object which is what is throwing the NPE you're getting; you only left it as: MediaPlayer m1p

Before setting the data source, you need to instantiate it with:

```
 m1p = new MediaPlayer();
```

Comment: Of course, i have always done that. Weird that i forgot it now. Thanks so much!